# SQL Union problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Here is my query:

```
SELECT publicationId AS PublicationID
  FROM dbo.PublicationOwner
 WHERE ownerId = 31331
UNION
SELECT AreaBuy.AreaBuyID AS PublicationID
  FROM AreaBuy 
  JOIN PublicationAreaBuy ON AreaBuy.AreaBuyID = PublicationAreaBuy.AreaBuyID
 WHERE PublicationAreaBuy.PublicationID IN (SELECT publicationId
                                              FROM dbo.PublicationOwner
                                             WHERE ownerId = 31331)
ORDER BY publicationId
```

What I am trying to do is:

Get the list of publication ID's where the owner id is equal to 31331 and add in (union) any areabuy ids (as publication id) if the publication id in the area buy table are in the results from the first query.

What is wrong?  And yes, 31331 is the correct owner id and does return a publication ID which is also in the area buy table.

Comment: Which version is "v.8"? 2000? 2005? 2008?

Comment: Hum... Odd case.  @flavour404, can you confirm that by running each of the queries on either side of the UNION, you get results ?   Also, are you trying this directly in SQL mgt studio, or is it extracted from a program ?

Comment: mjv, yes, each of the queries separately returns the expected result but together the area buy id is not listed in the result.

Comment: @favour404.  OK... (just covering the bases).  I'm assuming that for this tests, you have distinct values for the PublicationId and the AreaBuyId, but none the less it wouldn't hurt to have an UNION ALL rather than UNION.  Right ?

Comment: @flavour404.  The next steps could be to look at the query plan produced by SQL (there may be some weird thing happening owing to attempt at optimization by reusing the top query).  Another quick test could be to modify the first query slighlty so that it doesn't look like the subquery in the second one.  for example, change to select name, or PublicationID + 99 or some like that... or even: WHERE OwnerId = some different value.  Basically we need to shake that tree ;-)

Comment: @flavour404: SQL 2000 is v8, SQL 2005 is v9. SQL 7.0 is, er, v7!!!

Comment: Have you made sure both columns are of identical data type? You won't be able to produce what you want if they are of different data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the idea of a recursive CTE for this, since we want to add to the original list.

```
DECLARE @ownerid INT;
SET @ownerid = 31331;

WITH Publications AS
(
SELECT publicationId AS PublicationID, 'P' AS Rowtype
FROM dbo.PublicationOwner 
WHERE ownerId = @ownerid

UNION ALL

--Note, I am not using the AreaBuy table, because the info is in PublicationAreaBuy
SELECT a.AreaBuyID, 'A' AS Rowtype
FROM Publications AS p
JOIN PublicationAreaBuy AS a
ON a.PublicationID = p.PublicationID
)
SELECT *
FROM Publications
ORDER BY PublicationID
;
```

And... doing a join will stop any problems with NULLs in your IN clause.

Edit: This next query will work in versions prior to SQL 2005

```
DECLARE @ownerid INT
SET @ownerid = 31331

SELECT publicationId AS PublicationID, 'P' AS Rowtype
FROM dbo.PublicationOwner 
WHERE ownerId = @ownerid

UNION ALL

--Note, I am not using the AreaBuy table, because the info is in PublicationAreaBuy
SELECT a.AreaBuyID, 'A' AS Rowtype
FROM (
      SELECT publicationId AS PublicationID, 'P' AS Rowtype
      FROM dbo.PublicationOwner 
      WHERE ownerId = @ownerid
   ) AS p
JOIN PublicationAreaBuy AS a
ON a.PublicationID = p.PublicationID

ORDER BY PublicationID
```

Comment: Can't use the 'with' key word, my version of sql doesn't allow it.

Comment: @Rob: The SS2005 tag is my fault, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a classic mix up. I dont see any similarity between attributes publicationId and AreaBuyId.
It could be they are just very badly named columns :-). A union of such different attributes doesnt seem like the right way to go.

Why doesnt :

```
SELECT O.publicationId , A,AreaBuyId
  FROM dbo.PublicationOwner O
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.AreaBuy A
   ON O.AreaBuyId = A.AreaBuyId
 WHERE OwnerId =31331
```

Get you what you want?

Comment: Nope, i need the area buy id to appear in the publication id column as later on it is treated as such.